# DLink DI-524 Wireless Router - Too Weak - Suggestions for something more ballsy?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

Just tried out The DLink DI-524 wireless router.  Signal strength is good for up to maybe 50 feet.

I was figuring on having it centrally located, then being able to access it both up and downstairs.  Unfortunately it looks like this router just doesn't have the broadcast strength I need.

Suggestions for others?

Comment: suggestion: try superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a repeater for upstairs? I think 50 feet is decent for a consumer grade router.

Answer (score 1):

Some DIY ways:

[Soldering wire.](http://www.viddler.com/explore/babblin5/videos/7/)

[Parabolic.](http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template/index.html)

[Kitchen strainer](http://www.instructables.com/id/Wifi-Signal-Strainer-WokFi/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[D-Link DIR-655 Xtreme N Gigabit Router](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=530). Don't know how big a house you are talking about, but haven't had any problems with this router where I live anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Your router is a bit long in the tooth, and has anyway been discontinued by D-Link.
Modern routers have longer reach, the better-quality ones, at least.

If you like D-Link, you can go on their [site](http://www.dlink.com/), choose Home and Home Office, then Launch Router Selector to choose your router. However, you don't need to limit yourself to D-Link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considering replacing the aerials on the router for some higher gain ones.  This may be cheaper than a new router.